# SQL Server - Enable Proxy Without Dropping And Recreating It

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-agent

When I run the following proc:

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysproxies
```

I notice that one of my proxy accounts is not enabled ([related to this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/162734/113501)). I'd like to create a script to enabled all disabled proxy accounts, but my understanding is that you need to drop the account and recreate it to re-enable it. In the process of doing this you need to know the linked credentials, description, and linked subsystem.

Is there a way to do this without dropping the proxy account, maybe some sort of simple update statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [sp_update_proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-proxy-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) stored procedure to enable proxy.

> **sp_update_proxy**
>
> Changes the properties of an existing proxy.

```
USE msdb ;  
GO  

EXEC dbo.sp_update_proxy  
    @proxy_name = 'Catalog application proxy',  
    @enabled = 1;  
GO
```